# Will warnings cause problems in an Android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, warnings

I have warnings in my Android project, thought it builds fine and everything seems to work correctly at runtime. I would like to know if there are certain types of warnings that will cause problems down the road.

Comment: In general you should clean these up as best as you can do. If you post the messages, we can help you fixing the warnings.

Comment: okay thank i will when i get around to it, but i just want to know will warnings stop my project working correct in any way?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not.  It depends on the details. But in general, warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Depends. If have a warning that says "you have an unused string in your resources" - no. It just sits there and clutters code. No problem. If you have a warning that says "Method XY is deprecated" it might be bad. This means that your app may crash on future android versions because you can't rely on that method. Also many warnings of the new android tools are performance improvements. If you don't like wasting batteries, you should fix these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better check every one of them. Some of them are very dangerous and can signalize of potential problems that will appear in runtime. Some can influence your product in future only. Some doesn't matter. (of the latter two @alextsc writes in the comment). 
Try to understand the reason of every one - it is a good school. Liquidate them if you can.

But until you are very good in telling which warning is dangerous or not, don't block any warnings!